# Non-Jewish father: son of whom for an aliyah?

Tags: gentiles, names, children-parenting, torah-service

Let's say there is a person born of Jewish mother, but not a Jewish father. To further complicate things, the mother was raised secular and at a later point converts to Christianity. Does her change and religion change her status in any way, meaning she should not be named?

If so, whom should the person receiving the Aliyah say he is the child of?

Comment: Ben Avraham...?

Comment: Aaron: Note the value of using a descriptive title. Until @MonicaCellio retitled your question, I couldn't find the duplicate. (I thought I remembered there was one, I looked for for it, and I didn't find it.) Once she gave your question a more descriptive title, the duplicate turned up on the "Related" list (to the right), and now you can find answers waiting for you.

Comment: @msh210 But my question has the added component that the mother is not religious. i don't know if that truly determines whether or not her name shouldn't be used. There is an unsourced answer from the RCA handbook, but that's not very useful as it's unsourced.

Comment: Um... the RCA handbook is a source. In any event, if you're unsatisfied with the answers to that question as answers to that question, then see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers. And if you want to ask specifically about the case that the mother is not a religious Jew, then [edit] this question to indicate what's already been covered elsewhere (so people don't waste time answering that here) and to indicate just what your question now is.